# How to use breeze in aurelia?

Tags: breeze, aurelia

I am new to aurelia, and I use the skeleton-typescript-aspnetcore skeleton project to build my first application. The skeleton works fine, but when I followed aurelia-breeze plugin guide to integrate it to my application, I use

```
import breeze from 'breeze';
```

on a ts file, but there is an error: cannot find module 'breeze'. I googled so much that someone mentioned the d.ts file is missing, and I copy it from git(https://github.com/jdanyow/aurelia-breeze/blob/master/dist/aurelia-breeze.d.ts) to typings folder, but the d.ts file rose an other error in the first line, cannot find module 'breeze-client':

```
import breeze from 'breeze-client';
```

I checked the nmp folder(wwwroot/nmp), both aurelia-breeze and breeze-client are there,also, the same in package.json.

I compared the aurelia-breeze.d.ts with other d.ts file under typings folder,
the files come with the skeleton all named index.d.ts, and with a typings.json for decalaration.

So I suppose the error should be caused by typings configuration, and I Googled for a long time, but there is no answer, can you tell me how to make it work? thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I don't use TypeScript in my Aurelia app but I had the same problem integrating breeze. In the end I solved it (or rather found this workaround) by adding it as a simple script instead of loading it from the node_modules (or jspm_packages, depending which one you use).

This is my new main.js file:

```
export function configure(aurelia) {    
    aurelia.use
        .standardConfiguration()        
        .plugin('aurelia-knockout');

    return aurelia.start().then(() => {
        require(["../scripts/lib/breeze.debug"], function(breeze) {
            require([
                "../scripts/lib/breeze.savequeuing",
            ], function(savequeuing){
                aurelia.setRoot();
            });             
        });                     
    });    
}
```

Hope this helps. In my case I even integrate the breeze.savequeuing plugin of breeze after breeze itself has been loaded. There are probably better ways to do this though.

Also notice I use "require" as the module loader. I use the Aurelia CLI so I have set it in the aurelia.json file under "build" like this:

```
"loader": {
      "type": "require",
      "configTarget": "vendor-bundle.js",
      "includeBundleMetadataInConfig": "auto",
      "config": {
        "waitSeconds": 0,
        "paths": {
          "jquery": "../scripts/lib/cdn/jquery-3.1.0.min",
          "knockout": "../scripts/lib/knockout-3.4.0"          
        }
      },
....
}
```

and under "bundles" like this:

```
     {
        "name": "vendor-bundle.js",
        "prepend": [
          "node_modules/bluebird/js/browser/bluebird.core.js",          
          "scripts/lib/require.js"
        ],
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To use breezejs client with aurelia you must do as follows

1. Install the required packages.

> ```
> npm install breeze-client --save
> npm install aurelia-breeze --save
> ```

2. Configure dependencies on your module loader.

   In my case, I am using amd with requirejs thus the dependencies will be as follows...

> ```
> paths...
>
> "aurelia-breeze":'../node_modules/aurelia-breeze/dist/amd/aurelia-breeze'
> "breeze-client": '../node_modules/breeze-client/breeze.base.min'
> "breeze.modelLibrary": '../node_modules/breeze-client/breeze.modelLibrary.backingStore'
> "breeze.dataService": '../node_modules/breeze-client/breeze.dataService.webApi'
> "breeze.uriBuilder": '../node_modules/breeze-client/breeze.uriBuilder.json'
>  
>
> shims...
>
> 'aurelia-breeze': {
>         exports: 'BreezeObjectObserver',
>         deps: ['breeze-client', 'breeze.modelLibrary', 'breeze.dataService', 'breeze.uriBuilder']
>       }
>
> 'breeze-client': {
>         exports: 'breeze'
>       }
> ```

(requirejs config.js file and aurelia.json full files included below)

3. Import and initialize the library on your TypeScript project as you need

> ```
> import * as breeze from 'breeze-client'
>
>   breeze.NamingConvention.camelCase.setAsDefault();  
>   breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance('modelLibrary',
> 'backingStore', true);
> ```

4. It´s done!! you can now use breeze. i.e.

> ```
> const entityManager = new
> EntityManager'http://zzaapi.azurewebsites.net/breeze/zza')   const
> entityQuery = EntityQuery.from(‘Customers’);
>
> entityManager.executeQuery(entityQuery).then(queryResult => 
> console.log(queryResult.results));
> ```

(from Brian Noyes excellent course on  https://www.pluralsight.com/courses/building-data-centric-apps-angular-breezejs)

PS: I will post the full content of my requirejs config.js file and also the aurelia.json for aurelia cli build, take look and notice prepends, preload and shims.

```
//-------------------config.js----------------------------------------------
    require.config(
      {
        baseUrl: 'src',
        paths: {
    
          pipelines: 'resources/pipelines',
          templates: 'resources/templates',
          interceptors: 'resources/interceptors',
    
          bluebird: '../node_modules/bluebird/js/browser/bluebird.min',
          bootstrap: '../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min',
    
          "aurelia-animator-css": '../node_modules/aurelia-animator-css/dist/amd/aurelia-animator-css',
          "aurelia-binding": '../node_modules/aurelia-binding/dist/amd/aurelia-binding',
          "aurelia-bootstrapper": '../node_modules/aurelia-bootstrapper/dist/amd/aurelia-bootstrapper',
          "aurelia-breeze": '../node_modules/aurelia-breeze/dist/amd/aurelia-breeze',
          "aurelia-computed": '../node_modules/aurelia-computed/dist/amd/aurelia-computed',
          "aurelia-dependency-injection": '../node_modules/aurelia-dependency-injection/dist/amd/aurelia-dependency-injection',
          "aurelia-event-aggregator": '../node_modules/aurelia-event-aggregator/dist/amd/aurelia-event-aggregator',
          "aurelia-fetch-client": '../node_modules/aurelia-fetch-client/dist/amd/aurelia-fetch-client',
          "aurelia-framework": '../node_modules/aurelia-framework/dist/amd/aurelia-framework',
          "aurelia-history": '../node_modules/aurelia-history/dist/amd/aurelia-history',
          "aurelia-history-browser": '../node_modules/aurelia-history-browser/dist/amd/aurelia-history-browser',
          "aurelia-http-client": '../node_modules/aurelia-http-client/dist/amd/aurelia-http-client',
          "aurelia-loader": '../node_modules/aurelia-loader/dist/amd/aurelia-loader',
          "aurelia-loader-default": '../node_modules/aurelia-loader-default/dist/amd/aurelia-loader-default',
          "aurelia-logging": '../node_modules/aurelia-logging/dist/amd/aurelia-logging',
          "aurelia-logging-console": '../node_modules/aurelia-logging-console/dist/amd/aurelia-logging-console',
          "aurelia-metadata": '../node_modules/aurelia-metadata/dist/amd/aurelia-metadata',
          "aurelia-pal": '../node_modules/aurelia-pal/dist/amd/aurelia-pal',
          "aurelia-pal-browser": '../node_modules/aurelia-pal-browser/dist/amd/aurelia-pal-browser',
          "aurelia-path": '../node_modules/aurelia-path/dist/amd/aurelia-path',
          "aurelia-polyfills": '../node_modules/aurelia-polyfills/dist/amd/aurelia-polyfills',
          "aurelia-router": '../node_modules/aurelia-router/dist/amd/aurelia-router',
          "aurelia-route-recognizer": '../node_modules/aurelia-route-recognizer/dist/amd/aurelia-route-recognizer',
          "aurelia-task-queue": '../node_modules/aurelia-task-queue/dist/amd/aurelia-task-queue',
          "aurelia-templating": '../node_modules/aurelia-templating/dist/amd/aurelia-templating',
          "aurelia-templating-binding": '../node_modules/aurelia-templating-binding/dist/amd/aurelia-templating-binding',
    
          "breeze-client": '../node_modules/breeze-client/breeze.base.min',
          "breeze.modelLibrary": '../node_modules/breeze-client/breeze.modelLibrary.backingStore',
          "breeze.dataService": '../node_modules/breeze-client/breeze.dataService.webApi',
          "breeze.uriBuilder": '../node_modules/breeze-client/breeze.uriBuilder.json',
    
          jquery: '../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min',
          lodash: '../node_modules/lodash/lodash.min',
          moment: '../node_modules/moment/min/moment-with-locales.min',
          numeral: '../node_modules/numeral/min/numeral.min',
          pouchdb: '../node_modules/pouchdb/dist/pouchdb.min',
          text: '../node_modules/text/text',
          toastr: '../node_modules/toastr/build/toastr.min',
    
          "jquery-ui": '../node_modules/jquery-ui/dist/jquery-ui.min'
    
        },
        packages: [
          {
            name: 'aurelia-dialog',
            location: '../node_modules/aurelia-dialog/dist/amd',
            main: 'aurelia-dialog'
          },
          {
            name: 'aurelia-templating-resources',
            location: '../node_modules/aurelia-templating-resources/dist/amd',
            main: 'aurelia-templating-resources'
          },
          {
            name: 'aurelia-templating-router',
            location: '../node_modules/aurelia-templating-router/dist/amd',
            main: 'aurelia-templating-router'
          },
          {
            name: 'aurelia-testing',
            location: '../node_modules/aurelia-testing/dist/amd',
            main: 'aurelia-testing'
          },
          {
            name: 'aurelia-validation',
            location: '../node_modules/aurelia-validation/dist/amd',
            main: 'aurelia-validation'
          },
          {
            name: 'popper.js',
            location: '../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/',
            main: 'popper.min'
          }
        ],
        shim: {
          'aurelia-breeze': {
            exports: 'BreezeObjectObserver',
            deps: ['breeze-client', 'breeze.modelLibrary', 'breeze.dataService', 'breeze.uriBuilder']
          },
          'breeze-client': {
            exports: 'breeze'
          },
          bootstrap: {
            exports: '$.fn.button',
            deps: ['jquery', 'popper.js']
          },
          jquery: {
            exports: '$'
          },
          "jquery-ui": {
            exports: '$.autocomplete',
            deps: ['jquery']
          },
          lodash: {
            exports: '_'
          },
          "popper.js": {
            exports: 'Popper'
          },
          toastr: {
            deps: ['jquery']
          }
    
        }
      });
    
    require(['aurelia-bootstrapper']);

//-------------------aurelia.json----------------------------------------------
    {
      "name": "mgame",
      "type": "project:application",
      "bundler": {
        "id": "cli",
        "displayName": "Aurelia-CLI"
      },
      "platform": {
        "id": "aspnetcore",
        "displayName": "ASP.NET Core",
        "index": "index.html",
        "baseDir": ".",
        "output": "dist"
      },
      "transpiler": {
        "id": "typescript",
        "displayName": "TypeScript",
        "fileExtension": ".ts",
        "dtsSource": [ "./custom_typings/**/*.d.ts" ],
        "source": "src/**/*.ts"
      },
      "markupProcessor": {
        "id": "maximum",
        "displayName": "Maximum Minification",
        "fileExtension": ".html",
        "source": "src/**/*.html"
      },
      "cssProcessor": {
        "id": "sass",
        "displayName": "Sass",
        "fileExtension": ".scss",
        "source": "src/**/*.scss"
      },
      "editor": {
        "id": "visualstudio",
        "displayName": "Visual Studio"
      },
      "testFramework": {
        "id": "jasmine",
        "displayName": "Jasmine"
      },
      "unitTestRunner": {
        "id": "karma",
        "displayName": "Karma",
        "source": "test/unit/**/*.ts"
      },
      "e2eTestRunner": {
        "id": "protractor",
        "displayName": "Protractor",
        "source": "test/e2e/src/**/*.ts",
        "dist": "test/e2e/dist/",
        "typingsSource": [ "node_modules//@types/**/*.d.ts", "custom_typings/**/*.d.ts" ]
      },
      "paths": {
        "root": "src",
        "resources": "resources",
        "elements": "resources/elements",
        "pipelines": "resources/pipelines",
        "templates": "resources/templates",
        "attributes": "resources/attributes",
        "interceptors": "resources/interceptors",
        "valueConverters": "resources/converters",
        "bindingBehaviors": "resources/behaviors",
        "assets": [
          {
            "src": "node_modules/jquery-ui/dist/images/*",
            "dest": "/../images"
          },
          {
            "src": "node_modules/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css",
            "dest": "/css"
          },
          {
            "src": "node_modules/font-awesome/fonts/*",
            "dest": "/fonts"
          }
        ]
      },
      "build": {
        "targets": [
          {
            "id": "aspnetcore",
            "displayName": "ASP.NET Core",
            "index": "index.html",
            "baseDir": ".",
            "output": "dist"
          }
        ],
        "loader": {
          "type": "require",
          "configTarget": "vendor-bundle.js",
          "includeBundleMetadataInConfig": "auto",
          "plugins": [
            {
              "name": "text",
              "extensions": [
                ".html",
                ".css"
              ],
              "stub": true
            }
          ]
        },
        "options": {
          "minify": "stage & prod",
          "sourcemaps": "dev & stage"
        },
        "bundles": [
          {
            "name": "app-bundle.js",
            "source": [
              "[**/*.js]",
              "**/*.{css,html}"
            ]
          },
          {
            "name": "vendor-bundle.js",
            "prepend": [
              "node_modules/bluebird/js/browser/bluebird.min.js",
              "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.min.js",
              "node_modules/requirejs/require.js"
            ],
            "dependencies": [
              "jquery",
              "lodash",
              "moment",
              "numeral",
              "text",
              {
                "name": "aurelia-animator-css",
                "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-animator-css/dist/amd",
                "main": "aurelia-animator-css"
              },
              {
                "name": "aurelia-binding",
                "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-binding/dist/amd",
                "main": "aurelia-binding"
              },
              {
                "name": "aurelia-bootstrapper",
                "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-bootstrapper/dist/amd",
                "main": "aurelia-bootstrapper"
              },
              {
                "name": "aurelia-breeze",
                "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-breeze/dist/amd",
                "main": "aurelia-breeze",
                "exports": "BreezeObjectObserver",
                "deps": [ "breeze-client", "breeze.modelLibrary", "breeze.dataService", "breeze.uriBuilder" ]
              },
              {
                "name": "aurelia-computed",
                "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-computed/dist/amd",
                "main": "aurelia-computed"
              },
              {
                "name": "aurelia-dependency-injection",
                "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-dependency-injection/dist/amd",
                "main": "aurelia-dependency-injection"
              },
              {
                "name": "aurelia-dialog",
                "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-dialog/dist/amd",
                "main": "aurelia-dialog"
              },
              {
                "name": "aurelia-event-aggregator",
                "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-event-aggregator/dist/amd",
                "main": "aurelia-event-aggregator"
              },
              {
                "name": "aurelia-fetch-client",
                "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-fetch-client/dist/amd",
                "main": "aurelia-fetch-client"
              },
              {
                "name": "aurelia-framework",
                "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-framework/dist/amd",
                "main": "aurelia-framework"
              },
              {
                "name": "aurelia-history",
                "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-history/dist/amd",
                "main": "aurelia-history"
              },
              {
                "name": "aurelia-history-browser",
                "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-history-browser/dist/amd",
                "main": "aurelia-history-browser"
              },
              {
                "name": "aurelia-http-client",
                "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-http-client/dist/amd",
                "main": "aurelia-http-client"
              },
              {
                "name": "aurelia-loader",
                "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-loader/dist/amd",
                "main": "aurelia-loader"
              },
              {
                "name": "aurelia-loader-default",
                "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-loader-default/dist/amd",
                "main": "aurelia-loader-default"
              },
              {
                "name": "aurelia-logging",
                "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-logging/dist/amd",
                "main": "aurelia-logging"
              },
              {
                "name": "aurelia-logging-console",
                "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-logging-console/dist/amd",
                "main": "aurelia-logging-console"
              },
              {
                "name": "aurelia-metadata",
                "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-metadata/dist/amd",
                "main": "aurelia-metadata"
              },
              {
                "name": "aurelia-pal",
                "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-pal/dist/amd",
                "main": "aurelia-pal"
              },
              {
                "name": "aurelia-pal-browser",
                "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-pal-browser/dist/amd",
                "main": "aurelia-pal-browser"
              },
              {
                "name": "aurelia-path",
                "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-path/dist/amd",
                "main": "aurelia-path"
              },
              {
                "name": "aurelia-polyfills",
                "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-polyfills/dist/amd",
                "main": "aurelia-polyfills"
              },
              {
                "name": "aurelia-router",
                "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-router/dist/amd",
                "main": "aurelia-router"
              },
              {
                "name": "aurelia-route-recognizer",
                "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-route-recognizer/dist/amd",
                "main": "aurelia-route-recognizer"
              },
              {
                "name": "aurelia-task-queue",
                "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-task-queue/dist/amd",
                "main": "aurelia-task-queue"
              },
              {
                "name": "aurelia-templating",
                "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-templating/dist/amd",
                "main": "aurelia-templating"
              },
              {
                "name": "aurelia-templating-binding",
                "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-templating-binding/dist/amd",
                "main": "aurelia-templating-binding"
              },
              {
                "name": "aurelia-templating-resources",
                "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-templating-resources/dist/amd",
                "main": "aurelia-templating-resources"
              },
              {
                "name": "aurelia-templating-router",
                "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-templating-router/dist/amd",
                "main": "aurelia-templating-router"
              },
              {
                "name": "aurelia-testing",
                "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-testing/dist/amd",
                "main": "aurelia-testing",
                "env": "dev"
              },
              {
                "name": "aurelia-validation",
                "path": "../node_modules/aurelia-validation/dist/amd",
                "main": "aurelia-validation"
              },
              {
                "name": "bluebird",
                "path": "../node_modules/bluebird/js/browser",
                "main": "bluebird.min"
              },
              {
                "name": "bootstrap",
                "path": "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist",
                "main": "js/bootstrap.min",
                "deps": [ "jquery", "popper.js" ],
                "exports": "$.fn.button",
                "resources": [
                  "css/bootstrap.min.css"
                ]
              },
              {
                "name": "breeze-client",
                "path": "../node_modules/breeze-client",
                "main": "breeze.base.min",
                "exports": "breeze"
              },
              {
                "name": "breeze.modelLibrary",
                "path": "../node_modules/breeze-client",
                "main": "breeze.modelLibrary.backingStore"
              },
              {
                "name": "breeze.dataService",
                "path": "../node_modules/breeze-client",
                "main": "breeze.dataService.webApi"
              },
              {
                "name": "breeze.uriBuilder",
                "path": "../node_modules/breeze-client",
                "main": "breeze.uriBuilder.json"
              },
              {
                "name": "jquery-ui",
                "path": "../node_modules/jquery-ui/dist",
                "main": "jquery-ui.min",
                "deps": [ "jquery" ],
                "exports": "$.autocomplete",
                "resources": [ "jquery-ui.min.css" ]
              },
              {
                "name": "popper.js",
                "path": "../node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd",
                "main": "popper.min",
                "exports": "Popper"
              },
              {
                "name": "pouchdb",
                "path": "../node_modules/pouchdb/dist",
                "main": "pouchdb.min"
              },
              {
                "name": "toastr",
                "path": "../node_modules/toastr",
                "main": "toastr",
                "deps": [ "jquery" ],
                "resources": [ "build/toastr.min.css" ]
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    }
```